# How to pause audio recording in java

Tags: java, audio

I am writing an application to record audio from microphone and it is working fine. Now I want to implement pause and resume functionality in it but I am not getting how to pause the stream.

Following is the code to write audio to the file:

```
targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
targetDataLine.start();
AudioSystem.write(new AudioInputStream(targetDataLine), fileType, audioFile);
```

in the code snippet you can see `AudioSystem.write` is writing stream to file. 

Now I am not getting how to pause and resume this write method so please guide me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling [AudioInputStream.close()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#close%28%29).

Comment: he asked in his question about both pausing and resuming

Comment: @John OK good point. Look at all the methods for [`TargetDataLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/TargetDataLine.html) ***including*** (hint, hint) the methods inherited from `DataLine` ..

Comment: I did, but did not find the answer, did you?

Comment: Would you please write a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example about how to pause and resume recording?

Comment: @John *"I did, but did not find the answer"* What, you didn't see methods like `start()` & `stop()`?!?